# opencv example not working in OpenFrameworks

Tags: iphone, opencv, openframeworks

I have downloaded openframeworks from Github. I can run all the samples but if I am trying to run opencv example given in openframeworks. Its not working, showing 44 errors and errors are not common too. I think there linking files are also missing in github. Do you have any idea why only opencv example cant get executed ?

Comment: Are you using OSX X-code? What version? Or Windows?

Comment: I am using Mac OS X Version 10.6.7

Comment: openFrameworks github is a bit of a moving target at the moment. Try asking for help on the openFrameworks forums.

Comment: Looks like Reasonable option :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In, for example, iPhoneFaceSamplesSomething some files are missing that you can get from other parts of the project (jpg, xml) or just ignore (png). You get a ton of warnings because they added OS X libs which XCode ignore, no big deal. And then some libs are missing for the iPhone like opencv highgui and some other. You should try to get them from somewhere else or compile them yourself. The project definition is a bit messy, you can also file a bug in github.

Answer (score 1):

actually the answer to this is that the ofxOpenCv examples only work when run on the actual device. ofxOpenCv doesn't work in the simulator on iphone currently.

Answer (score 0):

Check the read me file for includes. Often times OF addons have dependancies that are not included in the download.

Also another thing that will get you sometimes is when you're running the incorrect profile on your system. Like OSX 10.5 instead of OSX 10.6. Also fiddle with the release and debug options(switch back and forth), that will often help (I know it sounds hack-ish).